# Сервер на Java для собственных нужд

Tags: java, сервер, веб-сервер

Поставил перед собой задачу написать сервер на Java, который сможет работать с БД, обрабатывать команды пользователей,быть готовым к тому,что из него сделают сервер,для обработки игровой логики (какой-нибудь простой онлайн-игры или android-игры) или же взять, и полностью работать с сайтом. В общем, я хотел бы для себя написать многофункциональный сервер.

Хотелось бы спросить,в какую сторону копать,куда лучше посмотреть и что и как лучше сделать?

Уже перелопатил много всего про netty, nio, но хотелось бы узнать мнение других людей.

Comment: Вам нужен хттп веб сервер (Tomcat, Jetty, Netty, Undertow - самые простые и легко конфигурируемые) и само веб приложение (.war). Копать надо в сторону того, как создавать веб приложения на жаве.

Comment: @aleshka-batman, Как я понял,Вы сейчас мне предлагаете готовые сборки веб-серверов, в моем же случае мне самому хочется написать сервер для приложений.

Comment: Сервер понятие растяжимое. Нужно определиться что будет делать это сервер и реализовать каждую функцию по отдельности.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр не понимаю зачем вам собственный сервер, когда есть готовые решения. Все что вам надо - это написать приложение, которое будет работать на сервере.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр вы говорите, что хотите написать свой сервер (получается, что вы хотите свой аналог Netty/Jetty/Tomcat/etc), а таким занимаются крупные конторы и специалисты. У 1 человека это займет не один год.

Comment: @aleshka-batman, ничего страшного, даже если и так. Просто на сколько я понял, мне предложили контейнеры для сервлетов. А для себя мне хочется написать что-то типа "приложения-сервера", которое можно поставить на реальный серв и удаленно им управлять, описав различный функционал. Наверное так корректнее будет формулировка.

Answer (score 2):

Так же можешь почитать про Spring. Достаточно удобная вещь для написания своего сервера + большое количество настроек через анотации, что существенно сокращает код

Comment: Да,спасибо. Давно трогал Spring, но потом как то ушел,а сейчас совсем забыл про него, и думаю, этим фрэймворком стоит воспользоваться для написания.

Answer (score 1):

самый базовый вариант- это изучать Java EE (Enterprise edition). Конкретные темы: Servlet Facelet. Если говорить о фреймворках, то sparkjava, Так же, если говорить о разработке под Android, то следует знать о таких технологиях как SOAP и REST, знать о OkHTTP и т.д. На самом деле, тема очень большая, но вот это азы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Если вдруг у Вас в архиве есть какие то полезные маст-хев ссылки,которые просто так не найти гуглением,я буду очень признателен,если Вы поделитесь ими!

Comment: @МишаковАлександр Все маст хев ссылки легко можно найти, sparkjava.com, вроде так, очень легкий фреймворк. Там есть и туториалы.